# 日本語に違和感: メタで質問する時に右に表示されるヘルプ: 質問方法

Tags: バグ, 対応予定, 翻訳, 日本語, メタ

メタで質問を投稿中、タイトル入力欄にフォーカスがある時に、以下のヘルプが右に表示されます。

> 質問方法
>
> スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティやサイトについての質問ですか？
>
> 詳細を含めて具体的に問題を説明し、事例も共有してください。
>   できる限り参考になる質問、回答、ユーザー、ページ等のリンクを含めてください。
>
> ヘルプ・センターを参考 »

- 「質問方法」: 方法というよりガイドラインに近い
- 「スタック・オーバーフロー...についての質問ですか?」と聞かれても答えのもっていきようがなくて困る
- 「ヘルプ・センターを参考」: 「参考ください」という言い方と同じような違和感があります

英語版

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about Stack Overflow?
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> visit the help center »

Comment: 提案できますが、どうしても誰かが編集しないと使えないので、どうしましょう？entoにすべてを頼むのがどうかなと思うが、自分の適当翻訳は支援になりますか？

Comment: @jmac 投げっぱなしが多くてすみません。「英語が残っている」系は、適当翻訳があると役に立ちます。「日本語に違和感がある」系は、私の違和感の中身を書き切れていないと思うので、私の方で案出しをします。

Comment: 現在このテキストは開発者しか触れない為、適用まで少々待ってください。

Answer (score 2):

> 質問するその前に
>
> メタは、スタック・オーバーフローそのものについてのQ&Aを対象にしたサイトです。
>
> プログラミングの質問であれば[main]でお願いします。
>
> 意見の出し合いに終わらず、具体的な回答が出せる質問・問題を歓迎します。
>
> これまでの経緯、考えたことなどを含め、なるべく詳しく書くことで回答がつきやすくなります。
>
> ヘルプセンターへ »